# Vertical alignmend tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm trying to produce a tree diagram with tikz with vertically and horizontally centered text in my nodes. The second is working but the text is not vertically aligned although I'm using "text centered". Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow = right,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm,level distance=4.5cm},
edge from parent/.style={thick,draw=blue!40!black!60},
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, thick,
    draw=blue!40!black!60, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=black!20!white,
    text centered, text width=2.75cm, text height = 0.5cm}]]
\node {Question}
child { node {\small Question}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do not use `text height` replace it with `minimum height=1cm`.

Comment: The `text height` is the distance from the baseline of the text to the top of the box with the text. Similarly there is a `text depth`, see also their descriptions in the manual. `text centered` is not described in the manual,  but I would guess that only relates to the justification of the text in the node. Anyway, as @salimbou says, I think `minimum height` is what you want to use here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `minimum height` and `font=\small` instead of `\small` in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow = right,
  level 1/.style=
  {
    sibling distance=1.5cm,
    level distance=4.5cm
  },
  edge from parent/.style=
  {
    thick,
    draw=blue!40!black!60
  },
  every node/.style = 
  {
    shape=rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    thick,
    draw=blue!40!black!60,
    align=center, 
    font=\small,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=black!20!white,
    text centered,
    text width=2.75cm,
    minimum height = 1cm,
  }
  ]
\node {Question}
child { node {Question}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `text centered` = `align=center` ? it is sufficient to use only one from both :-)