# How to align tikz node text vertically centered and horizontally left

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, nodes

Assume a tikzpicture consisting of three nodes with node text.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, text width=6.0cm,
       text depth=1.50cm, text height=0.4cm, line width=0.75pt},
    block_half/.style = {block, text width=2.75cm},
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto]
        \node [block, anchor=north east] (row0_col1) {
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
        \node [block_half, right=1cm of row0_col1] (row0_col2) {
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
        \node [block_half, right=1cm of row0_col2] (row0_col3) {
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I align the text in each node such that it is vertically centered and horizontally left?

Comment: Use `minimum height` instead of `text depth` and `text height`, see e.g. [Vertical alignmend tikz node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309824)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. But I would like to maintain a constant height and length of each node across multiple rows (not shown in the above example).

Comment: OK, but I don't see the problem. Won't you get that with `minimum height`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  You are right. I can achieve the desired outcome via `minimum height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify `text height` and `text depth`, that is the default behaviour. To have them all the same height, set a `minimum height`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, text width=6.0cm,
        line width=0.75pt,minimum height=2.5cm},
    block_half/.style = {block, text width=2.75cm},
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto]
        \node [block, anchor=north east] (row0_col1) {
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux \\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux \\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux \\
        };
        \node [block_half, right=1cm of row0_col1] (row0_col2) {
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
            \textit{Baz:} Qux \\
        };
        \node [block_half, right=1cm of row0_col2] (row0_col3) {
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a `\Centerstack` on the text, and adjusted the `text height` and `text depth`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, text width=6.0cm,
       text depth=.9cm, text height=1.00cm, line width=0.75pt},
    block_half/.style = {block, text width=2.75cm},
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto]
        \node [block, anchor=north east] (row0_col1) {\Centerstack{%
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux}
        };
        \node [block_half, right=1cm of row0_col1] (row0_col2) {\Centerstack{%
            \textbf{Foo Bar}\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux}
        };
        \node [block_half, right=1cm of row0_col2] (row0_col3) {\Centerstack{%
            \textbf{Foo Bar}}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]